# Add a figure object to AxesSubplot Gridspec

Tags: python, matplotlib, biopython

I am using Biopython's `Phylo` module to generate a tree, and further used `gcf` to save this current tree as a figure object of `matplotlib`.

```
tree = Phylo.read("my tree.nwk", "newick")  
Phylo.draw(tree)
tree_f=plt.gcf()
```

I want to be able to make use of this figure object in a subplot:

```
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2, height_ratios=[1, 1, -2, 2],
                             width_ratios=[1, 1, -2, 2], hspace=0, wspace=0) 
phyl_ax = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ht_ax = plt.subplot(gs[1])
```

How do I make `phyl_ax` take up a figure object?

I have tried `phyl_ax(tree_f)`, but this fails with:

> TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not callable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Phylo, but from the [documentation](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Phylo._utils-module.html) it looks like you just need to set your axes as a keyword:

```
phyl_ax=plt.subplot(gs[0])   
Phylo.draw(tree, axes=phyl_ax)
```

Comment: Tried this. It says: TypeError: draw() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axes'

Comment: draw expects a "matplotlib.axes.Axes" object and since I am using gridspec phyl_ax is a "matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot" object. Am I correct to assume that this is what causing it to give the error? Also is there a work around for this?

Comment: Don't think so.  If you do `isinstance(phyl_ax, matplotlib.axes.Axes)` do you get True?  Are you using the most recent version of Phylo?

Comment: Upgrading BioPython helped.